# Is there an iOS 6 "call history" API?

Tags: call, history, ios6

I got the iOS 6 beta email from Apple today.  I've been waiting for this release to see if any sort of call history API is present.  The iOS 6 release notes page is currently down and the API site only goes up to iOS 5.1, so I still can't find any info on it and was wondering if anyone else knows?

Basically I'm wanting to know if the call history database access that worked in iOS 4, that was removed in iOS 5, has by chance found it's way back to working in iOS 6?

```
NSString *p=@"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db";
sqlite3 *d;
if(sqlite3_open([p UTF8String], &d) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"call_history present");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(d));
    sqlite3_close(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above snippet doesn't work on iOS 6 beta 2 due to lack of read permissions for the call_history db.